# PHP page gets redirected without the execution of the rest of the script

Tags: php

I have the following script which takes data from the users and writes into a file using PHP.
The issue that I am facing is when i direct the page using "form action" the page gets redirected but the rest of the script is not executed meaning no new data is written to the file, but when I leave the Form action blank the data gets written. 
Below is the code:

```
 <html>
 <body>
    <form action="page.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="text_box"/>
        <input type="submit" id="search-submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['text_box'])) { //only do file operations when appropriate
    $a = $_POST['text_box'];
    $myFile = "t.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, $a);
    fclose($fh);
}
?>
```

Comment: Is the code you posted `page.php`? Also, `size=` is not a valid HTML attribute.

Comment: no this is index.php, I am directing it to page.php. Also 
I have removed the size parameter.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Please tell me what is not clear to you!

Comment: @Pink: Everything about the question.

Comment: If your form is posting to `page.php` and your file handling code is on `index.php`, of course it won't be executed.

Comment: @Truth: It most certainly is, though I can't see where the OP is using it.

Comment: Your code tests if the `text_box` input field has been submitted. But if you are posting to another page, it won't be submitted on _this_ page.  If you need to redirect afterward, call `header("Location: http://example.com/page.php");`

Comment: @Pink: Forms don't magically execute PHP code that's below them on the server-side. The PHP conditional merely comes into play when the page is re-requested with the form data filled in. In this case, you're not actually requesting index.php any more, but page.php; so this code needs to go on page.php, which is what gets the form data.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: not in inputs, seems like he removed it though.

Comment: @Truth: Scan for `<!ATTLIST INPUT` in [HTML 4.01 Transitional](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/loosedtd.html). It's there. Looks OK in [HTML 5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-input-element), too. AFAIR, `input`s are the _only_ place that `size` is valid.

Answer (score 1):

PHP won't save it automatically.  You need to submit the form for it to then execute with given data.

Also, your fopen is using 'w' which truncates the file, then writes to it.  So every time you save, the new data isn't appended onto the end, it replaces the current data.

Also, is this file called 'page.php'?  The only other solution I can think of with your code is to move the PHP code to the top of the file, before the `<html>`.

Comment: This file is Index.php, and Yes I am submitting the form. As you can see in the code when I leave the form action blank. Data gets written to text file.

Answer (score 1):

You're submitting your form to `page.php`, but your form handling logic is found on `index.php`. That's what's causing your problems.

Either submit to `index.php` rather than `page.php`, or simply move the form handling logic to `page.php`.

Comment: I am trying to take the data from index.php and write it to a text file, later I am directing it to a new page page.php where the written text file is processed. Now when I leave the form action blank data gets written but when it is directed to page.php it is not getting written

Comment: You don't understand how PHP works. PHP runs before the page is sent to the client, on the server side. It runs completely, then sends the output to the client. If you don't submit the form, the script will obviously not run. If you submit the form to a different page than the one the script you need is on, it will also not run (as the information is sent to a different page).

Answer (score 0):

When somebody submits the form, it will take them to 'page.php'. Whatever PHP is in that file will be executed. Any PHP in the file above (i.e. not in page.php) won't be executed - it will never be read.

Just an aside: I would check out a PHP framework like Yii or CodeIgniter to help you here. Handles a lot of these problems for you.